# Facebook SDK for Windows mobile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is it possible to use Facebook SDK for windows phone 8.1?
Because they are not providing a SDK currently although it was there before two years ago.
I'm working with Visual Studio Community 2015.
Can any one please tell me if there is a way to integrate Facebook with a Windows phone 8.1 app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which SDK does http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/ refer to? Though it has windows 8 in heading, but if you drill into any sub page, it mentions compatibility with 8.1 as well. For example, http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/config/